# How to create rust procedurally?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, node-editor

I've been trying to come up with an idea of creating rust procedurally and tried searching up for tutorials on various sites which only made use of image textures.
Procedural being a hard practise as it is, I wanted to create a rust texture for various meshes in blender but the one I did come up with, not so very realistic:[image]

does anyone have some ideas on how to create rust using only procedurals inside of blender?

Comment: First thing - rust does not fade in and out, a given point is either rusty it's not, not halfway rusty.  To create this effect run the noise texture you are using for a mask through a "Greater Than" node.

Comment: How's [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ceMxy.png)?

Comment: @PGmath, it looks like scrap paper stuck with glue on top on steeled suzanne but is it possible to create it in blender? It looks kind of intriguing.

Comment: @bzal the material PGmath would really work great and look good if it's a piece of worn leather. Hope he shares his node tree with us.

Comment: @hawkenfox, I tried it but it looks like a brown cow suzanne. I don't know if I can post a pic in the comment but I don't know how would it be used.  Could you demonstrate this?

Comment: @bzal  That's a first test, I meant to add an answer with an updated version yesterday, but I had a busy weekend.  I'll try to get it fixed up and an answer posted ASAP.

Comment: In the book "Blender 2.6 Cycles: Materials and texture cookbook" by Enrico Valenza, published by Packt publishing you can find more than 40 recipes, one of them is for procedural rust.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Hope the image is self explanatory enough. Hope it gives you a good starting point.

**Some Explaination**

Click on the image to view it in full resolution. You can copy the nodes and will get the same results. The Musgrave Texture are used as the mask to create the rust patch. A Second Musgrave Texture is given variation in the values, acts as the mask for the silver non rusty parts of the material. The noise material just provide a little color variation for the silver material, so it is not flat and boring.

The node pretty much tells you how it's constructed. The bottom image shows the closeup of the material, just for a visual reference that in closeup the material is still pretty convincing.

[image]

[image]

**Additional Side Notes**

> Regarding the UV image, I use it for visual testing uv unwrap to
>   prevent tile stretching on none procedure map, for this case I did not
>   use it at all as it is indeed a procedural material, so no uv work is
>   required on the model at all. It's just the default setup for my
>   workflow when I start a new file.

Comment: I don't know who down voted your answer, but I suspect you'd get a better rating by explaining a bit the logic behind your choice of nodes, rather than presenting just the image. On that note, think about displaying the most relevant information only, what are we learning  form the UV/image editor, the material library or most of what is on the right side of the first image... ?

Comment: @hawkenfox, what is the UV image for? Is it being used for texture paint?

Comment: @hawkenfox, would it be Ok if I made a tutorial based on this?

Comment: @ bzal go ahead whatever I share here is free and open. Well you could add a link on your video to this page when you are done.

Comment: @hawkenfox This is great... How would you increase the ratio of the rust to bare metal?

Comment: @Dontwalk Sorry for the late reply been buzzzing around lately ... so to answer your question I would just play with the values in the Musgrave texture since they were use to generate the rust patches. Play with it and experiment ... have fun most of all :)

Comment: What hex colors for the rust?

Comment: I was able to follow this in Blender 2.82a, it worked perfectly!