# How can I make metal look decayed and rotted

Tags: texturing, add-on

I want to make a plane look like its been decaying with rust holes in the jungle for decades like this picture.[image: WW2 Japanese Mitsubishi Betty]

I think I remember seeing an add-on that could do this, I could be wrong, but any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use this method: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76389/normal-map-when-painting-in-blender/76395#76395 Also you don't need to paint mask, you can use procedural texture for this.

Comment: Also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45553/how-to-create-rust-procedurally and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=37oBqhjDtBI and basically google "blender cycles rust/damage".

Comment: Not at all what I was asking. I want it to be so rusted that it has eating through the metal. I know how to make rust on an object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Final:

[image: final]

### Overview:

Basically you can use the same method as for creating any other rust material with one exception at the end - mix your rust material with **Transparent** shader trough "rust mask", created beforehand. This will create hard holes in your mesh. I've used **Greater Than** math node to harden texture.

[image: nodes]

> There is downside to this method. You can't add thickness to the mesh.
>   If you add Solidify modifier, the edges will be empty. You can try to
>   work around this with Volume texture but it could be an overkill.

Comment: Any way to work around the musgrave texture it causes blender to crash every time I use it

Comment: @BenSmith that's strange... What version of blender are you using? And what OS? I'll try something different.

Comment: 2.79 I'm running off CPU I don't have a graphics card in this computer that could be the reason. I even just tried the materials on a cube and it was running really slow.

Comment: @BenSmith I'm trying to make something without Musgrave. Hold on.

Comment: @BenSmith No luck. Only Musgrave gives this nice rim effect. Other textures are just hole/rust, without metal. Do you have 2.79b? Try maybe making it in experimental 2.8. How much RAM memory do you have? This setup is taking something around 60MB RAM with the cube from image.

Comment: I'll try 2.8 I have 2.79a. I have 6GB of ram with an i3-2100 CPU at 3.10 GHz

Comment: @cgslav I tried adding solidify modifier and it's fine. In fact, it looks great. There's a slight difference in the corrosion pattern between the two sides and it gives an effect reminiscent of the layered flaking that badly rusted metal goes through IRL. Wonder what I'm missing.