# Seamless grunge texture overlay across two materials

Tags: texturing

I'm making a sign and trying to wrap my head around how to apply a grunge mask overlay that will affect two separate materials seamlessly. The sign background needs to be one colour and the text a different colour, but I want the grunge to be applied across both in a realistic way. Here's a screenshot of the sign:

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: hello, maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ you can create a b&w mask

Comment: Read [How do I make a decal look worn](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/104373/how-do-i-make-a-decal-look-worn)

Comment: Also: [How to create rust procedurally](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45553/how-to-create-rust-procedurally)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A way to add a grunge texture to both the board and the letters with no discontinuity between the 2 would be to join your 2 objects (make sure that you've applied the *Scale* and that the normals are recalculate), unwrap  with *Smart UV Project* mode, paint your grunge texture on both with the *Stencil* brush option and use the result as a mask:

[image]

But the quickest way to is probably to use the grunge image in an *Image Texture* that you switch from *Flat* to *Box*, which allows the texture to be projected on the 3 dimensions, and use the *Texture Coordinate* "*Object*" output socket, with an empty as *Object* in order to control the location and scale of the texture so that you can precisely put the grunge:

[image]

[image]

Then use this node chain as a mask in both the letter and the board materials. Here for the board I use it to simply separate 2 nuances of red:

[image]

Former answer, in case your letters were printed and part of the same object:

You don't say enough about your current material, but let's suppose that is very basic, like this one (a simple mix between 2 colors with a b&w mask for the text):

[image]

then you can plug a dirt mask into 2 *ColorRamp* in order to get the dirty texture:

[image]

If your material is more complicated, for example because it plays with glossiness etc, it will make the node setup more complicated as well:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I should have provided more information about the setup. The text was created as a separate mesh and needs to protrude from the sign background to look as though the letters have been stuck on. Here's the .blend file: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6dWYegJe" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6dWYegJe/)

Comment: ok i've edited my answer, I hope it helps

Comment: moonboots you are AMAZING!! Thank you so much for the detailed steps, this works perfectly!! :D