# Convert node-based texture to exportable image

Tags: texturing, uv, unreal-engine

This is a follow-up to this post - [Seamless grunge texture overlay across two materials](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/205652/seamless-grunge-texture-overlay-across-two-materials/205656?noredirect=1#comment346387_205656)

I have my node-based texture (thanks to moonboots) and now I need to somehow get it into UE4. I read up on texture baking but I don't know if it makes more sense to try that or would it be easier to recreate the texture directly in UE4? I pressed the Bake button in Blender and it saved internally, how do I export that out into an image file?

Thanks

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13508/how-do-i-bake-a-texture-using-cycles-bake/13509#13509

Answer (score 0):

With your baked Image Texture selected in the Shading tab (the node should have a "selection outline" - like when you selected it before baking), you can easily save your image from the UV editing tab:

[image: SaveImage]

Comment: Hi Christopher. I should have mentioned in my question that there are two separate materials on the sign, one for the background and one for the text. The part I'm struggling with is creating a single image that keeps both material values in tact. Is it possible to bake two materials simultaneously into one image?

Comment: Yes you can. I've always found this video helpful - it's for 2.79, so it looks a bit different, but it still uses cycles (which is necessary for baking.) I'm sure you can figure the rest out - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9airvjDaVh4&feature=emb_title